What type of mineral ore was the Nostromo hauling?
I know Alien itself neglects to mention what kind of mineral ore they are hauling, but is it mentioned in the novelization or elsewhere?
It is hard to imagine even 20 million tons of pure gold (which would depress the price of gold severely) would pay for such a mission, although perhaps the idea is that some sort of technology that makes spaceflight cheap and routine has been developed.
I like this one aspect of Avatar: antigravity rocks would be damn valuable, I am pretty sure.

The novelization by Alan Dean Foster, which has some differences as it was based off a draft script says "the Nostromo was towing a considerable quantity of crude oil through the void between the stars, encased in its own automatic, steadily functioning refinery."

Already addressed here -> How much cargo did the Nostromo carry in her decks?.

It's not a perfect dupe, so I've edited the title of the other question to incorporate the issue of what she's pulling.

@Valorum the other question does have the type of stuff explained. Improbably petroleum is extracted from it. In the 22nd century??

@releseabe - The answer is the answer. It doesn't need to make sense because it's just a throwaway line to explain why they're driving around in a tugboat in space. Hence they need to be tugging something

@Valorum: In the same way that Sir Ridley spent so much effort on, for example, the eggs and the chestburster, you would think he would spend effort on this detail. I forgive him, however.

@releseabe - And then, of course, it needs to go boom at the end, so we need to fill it with something that goes boom.

@Valorum: It goes boom from its engines, no?

@releseabe - The refinery doesn't have any engines

I'm unsure that the rocks from "Avatar" defied gravity; I had the impression that the minerals involves were lighter than the planet's atmospheric gases.

@StanleyWebb: It seems to be a superconductor -- I see that the Wikipedia article indeed mentions Pandora's atmosphere but how useful would Unobtainium be if its properties depended on the atmosphere.

The justification for crude oil transport is that Earths oil supplies had been mined out and that oil products were still required for plastics.

@importrandom:  I guess one of the fundamental ideas of science fiction is spaceflight has become easy and cheap. But at least as things stand today, it is so expensive to transport mass from and to Earth that there is no substance that I know of that could be worth going anywhere close to us let alone lightyears away that could financially justify such a trip. That's why I liked Mars Needs Women -- that plot is much more plausible than so many others.

@Valorum: so the explosion was a combination of the fusion engines (or however they worked) plus the ignition of the oil? In space, oil does not burn. (The original catchphrase for Alien, btw).

@releseabe - Oil is explosive. Hence it exploded. From a screenwriting perspective, you call that 'job done, move on'
